# How to find a regression line for a closed set of data with 4 parameters in matlab or excel?

Tags: excel, matlab, dataset, regression

I have a set of data I have acquired from simulations. There are 3 parameters that go into my simulations and I get one result out.

I can graph the data from the small subset i have and see the trends for each input, but I need to be able to extrapolate this and get some form of a regression equation seeing as the simulation takes a long time.

In matlab or excel, is it possible to list the inputs and outputs to obtain a 4 parameter regression line for a given set of information?

Before this gets flagged as a duplicate, i understand polyfit will give me an equation of best fit and will be as accurate as i want it, but i need the equation to correspond to the inputs, not just a regression line.

In other words if i 20 simulations of inputs a, b, c and output y, is there a way to obtain a "best fit":

```
y=B0+B1*a+B2*b+B3*c
```

using the data?

Comment: "i need the equation to correspond to the inputs, not just a regression line" please expand on this? Surely that is exactly what a regression line is?

Comment: maybe im wrong but when i learned regression lines, they take an output set and expand it to fit into the y=ax+b or y=ax^2 +bx +c model. I need it to be as stated above.

Comment: You are wrong. The form you have posted above is canonical multiple regression. Depending on what version of Matlab you are running either just use `regress` or `fitlm`.

Answer (score 1):

My usual recommendation for higher-dimensional curve fitting is to pose the problem as a minimization problem (that may be unneeded here with the nice linear model you've proposed, but I'm a hammer-nail guy sometimes).

It starts by creating a correlation function (the functional form you think maps your inputs to the output) given a vector of fit parameters `p` and input data `xData`:

```
correl = @(p,xData) p(1) + p(2)*xData(:,1) + p(3)*xData(:2) + p(4)*xData(:,3)
```

Then you need to define a function to minimize given the parameter vector, which I call the `objective`; this is typically your correlation minus you output data.
The details of this function are determined from the solver you'll use (see below).
All of the method need a starting vector `pGuess`, which is dependent on the trends you see.
For nonlinear correlation function, finding a good `pGuess` can be a trial but necessary for a good solution.

---

### `fminsearch`

To use [`fminsearch`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html), the data must be collapsed to a scalar value using some norm (`2` here):

```
x         = [a,b,c];                       % your input data as columns of x
objective = @(p) norm(correl(p,x) - y,2);
p         = fminsearch(objective,pGuess);  % you need to define a good pGuess
```

### `lsqnonlin`

To use [`lsqnonlin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqnonlin.html) (which solves the same problem as above in different ways), the norm-ing of the objective is not needed:

```
objective = @(p) correl(p,x) - y ;
p         = lsqnonlin(objective,pGuess);  % you need to define a good pGuess
```

(You can also specify lower and upper bounds on the parameter solution, which is nice.)

### `lsqcurvefit`

To use [`lsqcurvefit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqcurvefit.html) (which is simply a wrapper for `lsqnonlin`), only the correlation function is needed along with the data:

```
p = lsqcurvefit(correl,pGuess,x,y);  % you need to define a good pGuess
```